# Import-Csv to get data that contains dash gives boxes or question mark

Tags: powershell, csv, import

I have a very peculiar error when attempting to import some csv data.
This data has links to files contained in a sharepoint site that need to stay the same. (I'm actually writing a script to delete these files).
My problem is these links in particular have dashes in them which either powershell seems to not recognize or the import-csv command cannot handle.
I also want to point out that there are two types of dashes. The hyphen is directly on your keyboard, these are the longer hyphens called "dashes" that are not directly on the keyboard.

If you're not sure what I mean, open up MS Word and FULLY type out the following:

```
This - is a test.
```

You will notice that MS Word will auto convert the hyphen to a dash when you strike the space bar before typing the "a" and it will be longer.

Please let me know how I can get powershell to recognize dashes!

Examples:

```
$web.getListItem("link contains -")
#finds file

#Please note below the actual text is: link contains -
$files = import-csv $path #csv is ms-dos csv
$files[0].Url
#Prints: link contains <box>
$files = import-csv $path #csv is excel general csv
$files[0].Url
#Prints: link contains ?
```

**Solved**

Figured this out.
I used the following site to figure out the hex equivalent of my character and did a substitute in excel.
http://www.asciitohex.com/ Turned out the hex equivalent was:

```
e2 80 93
```

or Url encode:

```
%E2%80%93
```

Comment: You should enter your solution as an answer instead of editing the question. (It's OK - and encouraged - to answer your own question when you've solved the problem.)

Comment: Because of my low StackOverflow status I could not answer my own question at the time I figured this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

Figured this out. I used the following site to figure out the hex equivalent of my character and did a substitute in excel. http://www.asciitohex.com/ Turned out the hex equivalent was:

```
e2 80 93
```

or Url encode:

```
%E2%80%93
```